# InstallShield Runtime?

Tags: build, runtime, installshield

We have InstallShield 2009 Premier installed on one system on which it is used to create and compile setups (one seat license).

However, we are trying to create a one-click-build-experience by using Team Foundation Build Server to do nightly builds. We would like to integrate the generation of the setup files as well.

I know that there is an open source package available on CodePlex that contains a custom build task for automating the generation of an installshield based setup (by submitting the .ism file and other stuff).

Is there something like an installshield runtime that can be installed on our build server which does nothing else then creating the setup from an ism file without UI or anything else so that we dont have to buy another license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InstallShield Premier includes a [Standalone Builder](http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/HelpLibDevStudio9/StandAloneBuild.htm) command line tool which you can install on your build server and use as part of an automated process.

I can't remember if this come on the CD or if you need to download it through the InstallShield updates.

Note that this is not included in the Professional edition anymore.

Comment: Awesome! There are many things that are not quite obvious in InstallShield (as if they ever were...). However,... I missed that thing. You're indeed right. We are going to install the SA Build (luckily we purchased the Premier Edition). Thanks man!

Comment: Getting the SAB is not obvious either. You have to download it from the "updates" dialog within InstallShield.

Answer (score 1):

For TFS integration, you need InstallShield 2011 as it will now work with TFS2010 and will build properly as long as the machine you are using to build on has the TFS build agent and the installshield Standalone build or InstallShield Pro/Premier edition. The generated installation will also be copied to the TFS drop folder.